# Swagger should not have both `example` and `examples`, as they are mutually exclusive

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm getting an issue with the swagger definition created from my spring boot application. The error is causing an issue with kubernetes deployments and is related to trying to display the example requestBody in swagger. This is the error I get from https://editor.swagger.io/.

```
application/json
should not have both `example` and `examples`, as they are mutually exclusive
Jump to line 31
```

The error is coming from the end of the config -> example: null

```
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/PromotionsRequestBody'
            examples:
              promotionsRequestBody:
                description: promotionsRequestBody
                value:
                  ncrc: '12345678'
                  divisionCd: 24
                  promoReq:
                    - unitType: 1
                      cics:
                        - 52030001
                        - 47150124
                        - 13400023
                      startDate: '2023-01-01'
                      endDate: '2023-12-21'
                  stores:
                    - 3427
                    - 3439
                  rogs: SHGN
                  storeGroup: 101
            example: null
        required: true
```

This is the code snippt of the swagger annotations used to display the example requestBody.

```
    public ResponseEntity<PromotionsDTO> getPromotions(
            @Parameter(name = "requestBody", description = "requestBody") @Valid
            @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(required = true, content = @Content(
                    examples = { @ExampleObject(name = "promotionsRequestBody", value = Constants.PROMOTIONS_REQUEST_EXAMPLE) })) @RequestBody PromotionsRequestBody requestBody)
    {
```

Does anynoe have any idea how to resolve this issue? There is no example option in the swagger3.

Comment: The unexpected addition of `example: null` looks like a bug, probably in the [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) library, or (less likely) in Springdoc or Springfox. Try using the latest version of Swagger Core (2.2.9 as of this writing) and if it doesn't help, [open an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: thank you, upgrading the version worked for me!